# Tag synonym request

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I've noticed that new `gm` tag has been created. I'd like to propose it be marked as a synonym of `grandmaster`.

I do not have the rep to make the change myself.

Comment: The [gm] tag now appears to have been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I agree!

And it looks like the gm tag has only been used for just one question.